# SQL SERVER - Need a Simple T-SQL Program to iterate date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, while-loop

My procedure that I am calling works on day by day basis. I need to pass/iterate by one day upto the current date to the procedure for it to perform the action. Can some help with that. Here is the sample that I tried but it fails to work. I am beginner.

```
USE [aaa]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @VarDate1  Datetime ='2015-09-30'
DECLARE @VarDate2  Datetime ='2015-09-30'


WHILE (@VarDate2 <= '2015-12-10') 
BEGIN
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[procname]
        @tday1 = @VarDate1 ,
        @tday2 = @VarDate2

SET @VarDate2 = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @VarDate2)
set @VarDate1 = @VarDate2

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
END
GO
```

Comment: Define `fails to work`. Do you get an error? Does it now loop? Also, why do you have 2 variables that are the same, always?

Comment: PLSQL and SQL SERVER are not same. please remove the plsql tags.

Comment: @ WEI_DBA  I do not get any error , the process does not end. The procedure needs start date and end date  so have them the same.

Comment: Put in an IF statement in your loop to check if the `@VarDate2 > '2015-12-10`. If it's true, then `Break Else Continue`. That should end your endless loop.

Comment: @mux Bad habits are hard to break and they make communication difficult. If your procedures needs start and end date arguments, then **WHY** did you name your variables VarDate1 and VarDate2? You need to try harder to become a better developer - and part of that is making your code more readable and more easily understood.

Comment: @mux But let's move on. Your loop is not the current problem. So you need to break your logic down into smaller, testable parts. Since your procedure needs start and end dates, does the procedure also assume that these dates are **NOT** the same value? Now would be a good time to check by manually executing the procedure with the values used in the first iteration. Does that work?

Comment: On top of what @SMor said, I would suggest that you try running your loop for one iteration first, i.e. `WHILE (@VarDate2 <= '2015-09-30')`, maybe your procedure takes longer to run than you think.

Answer (score -1):

By checking your code, you're probably getting an error while trying to set the value for @VarDate1 and @VarDate2. Try the code below:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @VarDate1 Datetime = CAST('20150930 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @VarDate2 Datetime = CAST('20150930 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)


WHILE (@VarDate2 <= '20151210') BEGIN

    SET @VarDate2 = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @VarDate2)
    SET @VarDate1 = @VarDate2

    PRINT @VarDate2 --Change your logic here
END
GO
```